Sum up column values by special logic
Say we have an array like:
a = np.array([
    [k11, k12, k13, k14, k15, k16, k17, k18],
    [k21, k22, k23, k24, k25, k26, k27, k28],
    [k31, k32, k33, k34, k35, k36, k37, k38],
    [k41, k42, k43, k44, k45, k46, k47, k48]
])

const = C

I need to create a vector from this array like this (runge kutta 4):
result = np.array([
    const * (k11 + 2*k21 + 2*k31 + k41),
    const * (k12 + 2*k22 + 2*k32 + k42),
    const * (k13 + 2*k23 + 2*k33 + k43),
        ....
    const * (k18 + 2*k28 + 2*k38 + k48)
])

I am able to do this in cycle, but I am pretty sure numpy methods allow this in vectorised form.

Please read tag descriptions before using tags. From [tag:python-3.x]: "DO NOT USE UNLESS YOUR QUESTION IS FOR PYTHON 3 ONLY. Always use alongside the standard [python] tag."

np.einsum solution:
result = const * np.einsum('ij,i->j', a, [1, 2, 2, 1])

ij,i are the dimensions of a and the coefficients. The result, j is missing i, which means that that dimension is multiplied and summed across the arrays.
This solution is nice because it is very explicit about dimensions without requiring any reshaping or transposition. For larger matrices or longer multiplication chains, the order of operations will be optimized for speed.

result = (const * np.asarray([1, 2, 2, 1])) @ a


First provide the weights of the coefficients via const * np.asarray([1, 2, 2, 1]).
Then calculate the product (think of it as a column-wise dot product or as a matrix-matrix product between a 1×4 matrix and a 4×8 matrix), making use of @.

Note that providing a minimal, reproducible example would help to compare the equivalence of mine and your solution.

Turned easy in several steps:
a[1, :] *= 2
a[2, :] *= 2
result = np.sum(a, axis=0)
result = const * result


Keep in mind that this will modify the a array. That might be fine, but I want to make sure people realize that.
